# SWIG: What's difference between %pointer_class and %pointer_functions?

Tags: python, c, swig

Here is my C inteface:

```
typedef uint16_t my_type1;
typedef uint8_t my_type2;
int my_func(my_type1 * arg1, my_type2 * arg2) {
   *arg1 = *arge + 1;
}
```

now it works if I define my interface file like this:

```
%include "stdini.i"
%include "cpointer.i"
typedef uint16_t my_type1;
typedef uint8_t my_type2;
%pointer_functions(my_type1, my_type1_p);
%pointer_functions(my_type2, my_type2_p);
```

But I can't seem to get it work with `%pointer_class`. It always give me error:

> TypeError: Couldn't Convert opaque Python pointer to C pointer.